# Run mobile apps with URL by deep linking URI that contains the QR Code decoded data at apps particular location

Tags: android, url, uri, qr-code, deep-linking

In order to Run this app in the Mobile Devices such as Phone or Tablets, MUST DO (**Current process**) :-

**TO CREATE NEW USER or ACCOUNT,**

1). User must owned a PC/NOTEBOOKS/LAPTOPS (QR Code can only be generated here), this is the step I want to SKIP by using Deep Linking URI :-
        a). Goto URL/Web Login,
        b). Click on Generate QR Code button (decoded QR data is something like this "http://trialgame.com?qr=ABCDE8 : TRY GAME")
        c). QR Code will appear on the PC monitor waiting for Phone/Tablets to scan,

2). User MOBILE DEVICES (Android and or IOS Phones/Tablets)
        a). Install Mobile Apps from a dedicated weblink & Run,
        b). Select "Add New Account",
        c). Select "SCAN QRCODE TO ENTER"
        d). QR Scanner activated in the mobile phone screen,
        e). Scan the QR Code generated from PC as 1(c ) above.
        f). App requested user to set the Gesture Unlock Pattern for future re-login.

---

What I'm trying to achieve with the Deep Linking URI (to help generate QR Code for those users without PC/Notebook/Laptops) :-
1). As the Admin,
    a). I will Generate the QR Code with my PC (on behalf of the user),
    b). Decode QR by using my available QR Scanner app to obtained the QR data,
    c). Append the URI created with the decoded QR data,
    d). I'll SMS or Whatapp to user the final URI,
    e). User click on the URI and app respond as though user mobile phone has just scanned the QR Code, 
    f). App requested user to set the Gesture Unlock Pattern for future re-login.

Conclusion, this Deep Linking URI is to ease those users who don't have access to PC/Notebook/Laptops.

This is what i've tried but not working,

1). trialgame://qr=ABCDE8

2). android-app://com.trialgame.androidapp/http/trialgame.com?qr=ABCDE8